# Python module for implementing binary file formats?

Tags: python, templates, resources, binary

I frequently find myself needing to write code to interact with binary file formats for which there aren't existing tools.  I'm looking for an easy way to implement readers/writers for structured binary formats -- ideally something that will let me create the reader using some sort of simple declarative format.

I've found the [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/) module, which works but seems to have been largely abandoned by the author.  I'm wondering if there are any alternatives out there that people have worked with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I'd use the [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module, but I may be biased as I wrote it. There's some simple code for reading/writing a binary format in the [manual](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/walkthrough.html#constructing-a-bitstring) as an example.

This is one way to create via a binary format:

```
fmt = 'sequence_header_code,
       uint:12=horizontal_size_value,
       uint:12=vertical_size_value,
       uint:4=aspect_ratio_information,
       ...
       '
d = {'sequence_header_code': '0x000001b3',
     'horizontal_size_value': 352,
     'vertical_size_value': 288,
     'aspect_ratio_information': 1,
     ...
    }

s = bitstring.pack(fmt, **d)
```

and one method to parse it afterwards:

```
>>> s.unpack('bytes:4, 2*uint:12, uint:4')
['\x00\x00\x01\xb3', 352, 288, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home).